# Freezed - group of sealed classes, some with fields that others don't have - causes bloc.state not to be able to access the missing fields

Tags: flutter-bloc, freezed

I have these sealed classes for the state of a cubit:

```
part of 'logged_out_nickname_cubit.dart';

@freezed
abstract class LoggedOutNickNameState with _$LoggedOutNickNameState {
  factory LoggedOutNickNameState.initialised(
          LoggedOutNickNameViewModel vm, String nickNameKey, FormGroup form) =
      _Initialised;
  factory LoggedOutNickNameState.submitted(LoggedOutNickNameViewModel vm) =
      _Submitted;
}
```

Here is the cubit:

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:reactive_forms/reactive_forms.dart';
import 'package:vepo/domain/user_registration/use-cases/logged_out_use_cases/get_user_field_from_local_use_case.dart';
import 'package:vepo/presentation/modules/logged_out/logged_out_nickname/logged_out_nick_name_view_model.dart';

part 'logged_out_nickname_state.dart';
part 'logged_out_nickname_cubit.freezed.dart';

class LoggedOutNickNameCubit extends Cubit<LoggedOutNickNameState> {
  LoggedOutNickNameCubit(
      this.vm, this.nickNameKey, this.form, this.getUserFieldFromLocalUseCase)
      : super(LoggedOutNickNameState.initialised(vm, nickNameKey, form)) {
    form.control(nickNameKey).value =
        getUserFieldFromLocalUseCase.invoke(nickNameKey);

    form.markAsDirty();
  }

  void submitPressed() => emit(LoggedOutNickNameState.submitted(vm));
  void initialise() =>
      emit(LoggedOutNickNameState.initialised(vm, nickNameKey, form));

  final LoggedOutNickNameViewModel vm;
  final String nickNameKey;
  final FormGroup form;
  final GetUserFieldFromLocalUseCase getUserFieldFromLocalUseCase;
}
```

The issue is that within the view, I try to access `loggedOutNicknameCubit.state.form` and since the form does not exist on one of the sealed classes, it is not recognised as being on the bloc state, and cannot be used in my view:

> The getter 'form' isn't defined for the type 'LoggedOutNickNameState'

The fix is to add the field to all sealed classes that don't use it as nullable like so:

```
factory LoggedOutNickNameState.submitted(LoggedOutNickNameViewModel vm,
      {@nullable @Default(null) FormGroup form}) = _Submitted;
```

Is there a way to silence the error that doesn't involve adding the field as null to the sealed class that doesn't need it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast to get those variables

```
(loggedOutNicknameCubit.state as _Initialised).form
```